# Android NDK error

Tags: android, error-handling, android-ndk

When using the Android NDK got this error:

```
07-06 19:37:03.245: INFO / DEBUG (3374): # 00 pc 00,068,592 / system / lib / libdvm.so
07-06 19:37:03.249: INFO / DEBUG (3374): # 01 pc 00,068,846 / system / lib / libdvm.so
07-06 19:37:03.249: INFO / DEBUG (3374): # 02 pc 0006806a / system / lib / libdvm.so
07-06 19:37:03.249: INFO / DEBUG (3374): # 03 pc 0001d9b0 / system / lib / libdvm.so
07-06 19:37:03.249: INFO / DEBUG (3374): # 04 pc 0002fd48 / system / lib / libdvm.so
```

How to decipher it?

P.S. I tried this:

```
[user @ localhost HelloNDK] $ ../../android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-eabi-addr2line-C-f-e / system / lib / libdvm.so
../../android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-eabi-addr2line: '/ system / lib / libdvm.so': No such file
```

It did not work: (

Comment: Is that the entirety of the error message?

Comment: please edit your answer, and share screen of shared libraries' folder, and Android.mk codes.

Answer (score 0):

libdvm.so is the dalvik VM, which I highly doubt is the cause of your bug.  More likely is that your doing something you shouldn't which puts it in a bad state.

You'll also need to get the dalvik vm's source code to properly deal with the error: http://source.android.com/ otherwise addr2line can't do much of anything.